# Other than the file extension and execution, how to determine if a file is a PowerShell script vs a Bash script?

Tags: linux, windows, powershell

**Other than checking the file extension,** what is the best way to check if an arbitrary file is a PowerShell script or not on a linux platform?

Comment: the extension is the BEST way to do it ... but you can also test the file for something specific to the lingo in question. the 1st line in many bash scripts is pretty specific to bash.

Comment: Is it not possibly to write a document that's both valid PowerShell code and valid Bash code?

Comment: Powershell has a built-in parser that you can use to parse a string (or file) and determine whether it’s valid Powershell - you *could* use that. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.language.parser.parsefile?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0#System_Management_Automation_Language_Parser_ParseFile_System_String_System_Management_Automation_Language_Token____System_Management_Automation_Language_ParseError____